# Confusion about linear combination of atomic orbitals (LCAO)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory, tight-binding

In an YouTube video, that I used some information from it to work out my homework,

Link: https://youtu.be/5vOvjeTRcqM?si=NzIcx_9QTNQ9Nhff

the linear combination of atomic orbitals (LCAO) was discussed for a lattice where the atoms are far apart from each other. The lattice function was written properly as a sum of Bloch states.
$$
\Psi_n(\textbf{r}, \textbf{k}) = \sum_{\textbf{R}}e^{i\textbf{k}\cdot \textbf{R}}\psi_n(\textbf{r}-\textbf{R}).
$$
Then at moment **7:29** he says that this sum is *not valid* any more when we bring the atoms of the lattice close together, because now the atomic orbitals have somefinite overlap. We shall construct new orbitals using Löwdin precipitation.

Now, my professor said to me that I shouldn't say 'not valid', because these Bloch sums are the same ones that we can still use to discribe the lattice. I also discussed in my homework the overlap matix, and how we can overcome the non-orthogonality difficulty.

And now I am fully confused, what is what. **Are the Bloch sums really not valid if overlap exists and they are valid only after using the overlap matrix/Löwdin prescription to get rid of the overlap and obtain orthogonality?**